# Let $f,g$ be linear operations $V \to V$ such that $\ker f=\ker g$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f,g$ be linear operations $V \to V$ such that $\ker f=\ker g$. Following statement is true: $\text{Im } f=\text{Im }g$

I'm a newbie linear algebra but i know that $\dim \ker f+\dim \text{Im}f=\text{dim}V$. So $\dim \text{Im}f=\dim \text{Im}g$

Answer (score 3):

This seems false to me... Let $f,g: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by: $$f(1,0) = g(1,0)= (0,0), \quad f(0,1) = (0,1), \quad g(0,1) = (1,1).$$ Then $\ker f = \ker g$, but the images are different. The dimension is the same, though.

(linear maps are known if you have their value in a basis of the space)

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7t290f7h580694_rankarankb  therefore , that solution is wrongs?

Comment: The solution there seems ok to me, but it is another problem. Here, you can only conclude from $\dim\,{\rm Im}(f) = \dim\,{\rm Im}(g)$ that ${\rm Im}(f) = {\rm Im}(g)$ if you have one of the inclusions and know that said dimension is finite. There's a lot more hypothesis there.

Comment: How would like if imf=im g and ker g =ker f?

Comment: I didn't understand your question now, sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $\text{Im} f=\text{Im}g$ and $\ker f=\ker g$ then exist $h$ such that $hf=g$ and $h$ non singular?

Comment: If ${\rm Im}(f) = {\rm Im}(g)$ and $\ker f = \ker g$, then $f = g$. You can take $h = {\rm id}_V$.

Comment: i don' thing so, if $f$ nonsingular and $g=id_V$ then $f \not=g$

Comment: I think the issue here is logic, not linear algebra, maybe. IF ${\rm Im}(f)={\rm Im}(g)$ and $\ker f = \ker g$, THEN $f = g$. The point is that ${\rm Im}(f)={\rm Im}(g)$ is not, in general, true (e.g, the example in my answer). I think that the most appropriate question would be: if $\ker f = \ker g$, do we have $h$ non-singular such that $h\circ f = g$? And for this question, I have to think a bit.

Comment: if $f$ nonsingular then $ker f=0$ and  $g=id_V$ then $\ker g=0$ and $\text{Im}f=\text{Im}g=V$